# How to make my php slider work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, slider, nivo-slider

My php slider is sort of working i have managed to get it to link to my database. However, i need it to loop through all the images within my slider and my code isn't work but i believe i have missed a loop query?!

THIS IS MY CODE WHERE MY SLIDER IS:

```
<div class="theme-dark 16 columns">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

            <img src="<?php print $row['image']?>"/>
           <!--  <img src="images/nivo/arts.png" alt="the grand theatre and nothern ballet">
            <img src="images/nivo/slider3.png" alt="leeds night light slider image">
            <img src="images/nivo/slider2.png" alt="Leeds Trinity slider image">
            <img src="images/nivo/slider4.png" alt="leeds art hotels">
            <img src="images/nivo/slider1.png" alt="leeds art slider image"> -->
        </div>
</div>
```

THIS IS MY CODE TO RUN MY SLIDER AT THE MOMENT:

```
<?php

$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM SliderImg";

$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($con));


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop in your php:

```
<?php
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM SliderImg";

$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'image' => $row['image'];
    )
}
?>
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div class="theme-dark 16 columns">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php 
        foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
            <img src="<?php print $row['image']?>"/>
        <?php 
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
   $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM SliderImg";
   $result = $con->query($myQuery);
   if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
?>
<div class="theme-dark 16 columns">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
      // use a while here
       <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
           <img src="<?php print $row['image']?>"/>
       <?php  } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the answer was as per the request and the code written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach to loop through your data, like this

```
<div class="theme-dark 16 columns">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

        <?php foreach ($row as $key => $item): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $item['image']?>"/>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

hope it help..